# How do HTML forms protect against email spoofing?

Tags: html

I can't find anything on this but it seems like a big problem. My concern is with HTML forms which contain an email field which the recipient can use to reply. What stops malicious users from inputting any old email address resulting in the spoofed email address receiving the reply? Isn't this quite a big issue and why isn't it abused?

Comment: do you mind elaborating a little more? not exactly sure what your concern is.

Comment: Do you mean using the form to fake the senders address?

Comment: This is an age old issue and it's down to the developer to ensure direct content is not passed to the recipient, It's not common to find contact forms that directly send emails to any email entered in a box. Email confirmations are used frequently to make sure the email address was linked to that user. You may often see a message in emails 'If you did not request this email, please ignore it' I suggest you don't lose any sleep over this :)

Comment: @m.edmondson Exactly so if someone wanted to spam a spoofed email address they could just use this address in place of their own in which case the reply would go the the victim (who owns the spoofed address).

Comment: A form would do nothing more than if you used any e-mail client to send via the same SMTP.  Senders address can be spoofed and it happens all the time.  IMHO the form doesn't add any extra attack vectors.

Comment: Someone who wants to spam a victim would probably use some other way than submitting an auto response form multiple times, you would think if they are clever enough to submit a form quickly multiple times then they should be clever enough to write a piece of code that can send spammy emails without the need of a form (which would be able to send a lot more emails and faster than submitting a form)

Comment: @m.edmondson But using any email client to send emails means the source email address is the same. What I'm saying is that an attacker could visit many different websites which contain HTML forms, add in some bogus text in the content fields, and use the victims email address in the 'Senders email' field. This would result in many reply emails going to the victim, where each email comes from a different address.

Comment: Different websites = different SMTP servers.  You would just reconfigure the client.  I agree with @Pete this is highly automateable that you just remove the 'middle man' form.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no sense. Hackers do something either for benefits (better if its a financial profit) or fun. There is no benefit or fun if someone else receives an e-mail. For you, as a hacker, what is the purpose of such "spoofing"?

Of course, you can fill the form at some web-site and specify someone else's e-mail as a reply address. He will receive the e-mail, see "if you think that you have received this e-mail by mistake - ignore it" and he will follow this instructions.

If you are a developer of such feedback form, then you would probably want to implement a limitation on the amount of such requests on one e-mail per hour; or IP address; or whatever else to prevent SMTP server overloading and making your actual or potential clients angry.

Comment: They could use a bot to send out thousands of e-mails.  Attempt to overload your SMTP?

Comment: Well if an attacker does this hundreds or thousands of times he could get some fun out of it. The victim could get thousands of emails coming from legitimate email addresses.